# Unpacking .NET collection into Pandas dataframe more quickly than Python iterator

Tags: python, .net, pandas, cython, osisoft

I have built a Python wrapper around a .NET API. The wrapper is currently very slow at "unpacking" a .NET collection object into the desired `pd.Series` object to be returned. I would like to accelerate this part of the code by wrapping some C code to do the unpacking.

**Detail**

This API  (specifically the [OSI Pi AFSDK](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Documentation/PI-AF-SDK/html/1a02af4c-1bec-4804-a9ef-3c7300f5e2fc.htm)) is used to retrieve timeseries data from a proprietary database.  The API call is achieved using the `pythonnet` library and returns a .NET collection called an [AFValues](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Documentation/PI-AF-SDK/html/T_OSIsoft_AF_Asset_AFValues.htm) object. The object is a collection of [AFValue](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Documentation/PI-AF-SDK/Html/T_OSIsoft_AF_Asset_AFValue.htm) objects, which themselves each contain a `timestamp` and a `value` field, amongst other information. At present I "unzip" each of these objects using a Python list comprehension and combine together to form the series. Here's a much simplified version:

```
timestamps = [afvalue.Timestamp for afvalue in afvalues] 
# (There is actually some timezone handling etc in the above as well)
values = [afvalue.Value for afvalue in afvalues]
result = pd.Series(index = timestamps, data = values)
```

This list comprehensions are noticeably slow on very large collections (ie. millions of values).

**Desired outcome**

Ideally I would like to:

- Call the API using the existing `pythonnet` code
- Pass the `AFValues` object into some precompiled code written in C (or maybe .NET? open to suggestions)
- Have the C code return a `Numpy` array or similar to convert to a Pandas object.

I believe the above is how Pandas and Numpy achieve their speed in large operations. Is the above the right approach, and any suggestions on how I would go about coding this?

Comment: The collection speed will be limited by the capacity of the archive subsystem on the PI Data Archive to process the RPC and return your values. One thing you want to be careful with is that you're not periodically re-retrieving that same large batch of historic data repeatedly. If it's possible to update the dataset incrementally using smaller chunks, that may be more efficient.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the comment. Yes agree repeat requests to the server for the same data is something I avoid doing - these sort of "bulk requests" tend to occur when I need to do a piece of one-off analysis involving a number of years of plant data. The challenge I'm trying to solve here is how to speed up that process of data transfer. Any advice on the C or .NET aspects I've outlined above?